# Get ListView selected item in gxt 2.0.1

Tags: gxt

I have a listview(gxt) with 2 columns, Name and Address. I've loaded the clients onto the listview(gxt), and now I want to select a client on the listview, and each time another listview box will display the Name & Address of the selected client. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Listview.getSelectionModel().select(..)

Or you mean select using the mouse? You will need to listen for the Select event. In this case have a look at:
[ListView Java Doc](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxtdocs/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/ListView.html), Events: Select...